# vs2015 Cocossharp beginner's guide

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, cocossharp

i'm trying to get into 2d game development. my eyes are on cocossharp. now the guides that are out there quite outdate. with MS buying xamarin a few months ago i'm not sure how i can make this work as all the guides are stuck with the old xamarin studio. take this for example:

[Sample Guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/game_development/cocossharp/first_game/part2/)

i've tried setting up a project using the cocos application but the resulting project is nowhere near what it should like in the guide [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXfXu.png)

the resulting project is a C++ project. i need your help to guide me in the right direction. please.

Answer (score 2):

Download the [cocossharp templates](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30701/cocossharp-project-templates-for-visual-studio).  You can also download many existing game [project examples in the mono repo](https://github.com/mono/cocos-sharp-samples).